# How to add javascript/jquery to product custom attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created two attributes from magento catalog attributes. I want to hide and show attribute on basis of second attribute value. I added a js file to the main.xml file like this :

```
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/custom.js</script></action>
```

Now i want to alert a value of attribute for that i added `alert($('#is_product_returnable').val());` to the custom.js file.

But its not working. How can i achieve this using my custom.js file or is there any other way i can hide/show attribute?

Comment: can you post a website link ?

Comment: No i can't but this is the error i am getting `TypeError: $(...) is null`

Comment: please show an HTML for this element : `is_product_returnable`. Also are you using jQuery OR prototype ?

Comment: This is the html for the attribute :                                                            `<select class=" select" name="product[is_product_returnable]" id="is_product_returnable">
 <option selected="selected" value="0">No</option>
 <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>`

Comment: just trying to alert value for this attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prototype, use this:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    alert($('is_product_returnable').getValue());
});
```

For jQuery, use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert(jQuery("#is_product_returnable").val());
});
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work .

Comment: check updated answer